# I want to call HttpPost of Partial view on submit but it calls HttpPost of ParentView Always. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, partial-views

I am using partial view inside a view (parent view)

I have a form in Partial view and when I click on submit button of partial view I want to call [HttpPost] method of partial view... but it doesn't get called it calls only the [HttpPost] of parent view...

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ParentView(Model model)
        {

            return View();
        }
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PartialView(Model model)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Check the form action is set to the correct action/controller. Sounds like it's pointing at the parent action at the minute.

Comment: You might want to edit the title of your question. Currently, it's not very descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions,

First:  Pass controller and action name explicitly to BeginForm method

```
using (Html.BeginForm(“MyActionName”,”MyControllerName”, FormMethod.Post)) {
```

Second: use jquery to do the submit. For this, first setup an id on the form and call submit on it using a the click event of standard html input (type=button)

```
using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "partialViewForm"})) {

$(‘#partialViewForm’).submit()
```

Comment: Got the solution... To add partial view to main view it needs to add using RenderAction()

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution... To add partial view to main view it needs to add using RenderAction()

Comment: Could you post some code to demonstrate the solution